# VS2008 Connection with Windows Embedded Compact 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-embedded-compact

I have visual studio 2008 SP1 with framework 3.5. I have a device which has a operation system as Windows Embedded Compact 7. Now whenever I try to deploy my application on that device at that time I got an error that  the bootstrap cannot be loaded. Device connectivity problem.
Please any one has suggestion about it.

Thank you so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this issues by providing a SDK file which is called SDK.msi file for that particular device and we can provide kind of communication between device and visual studio through that SDK file.